# Changing the tabStrip color for my FragmentTabHost

Tags: android, android-tabhost

Hi I'm currently doing a project wherein I need to make a custom tab on bottom of the screen. Well I already managed to do a FragmentTabHost but I still can't configure the tabstrip part because I really need to change it's  colors.

here's the code so far:

XML bottom_tabs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>
    </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

and the fragemtActivity code for settingup the tab:

```
setContentView(R.layout.bottom_tabs);

mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

        Bundle b = new Bundle();

        b.putString("0", "Me");
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("me").setIndicator(null,getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.selector_me)),
                FragmentMe.class, b);

        b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("1", "Social");
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("social").setIndicator(null, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.selector_social)),
                FragmentSocial.class, b);
```

On this part I can't tell why I cant configure the part for tab stip while I can configure the dividers appearance by adding this line after the code:

```
mTabHost.getTabWidget().setShowDividers(LinearLayout.SHOW_DIVIDER_NONE);
```

Well I just thought that this part may help but what I really need to do for now is just to change the TabStrip color. Thanks!

Here's what it look like so far:

obviously it's using android default tabstrip which is what I need to change from blue into green of same hex with the icons.

[image]

Comment: can you post some images how it is now..and how they want you??

Answer (score 0):

1.> Create a xml layout file for your tab indicator

2.> Inflate the view

3.> set the view in setIndicator method

I have use this way in TabHost it works

Eg xml file with text as tab indicator

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:background="@drawable/tab_selector"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Whatever You Want" 
    android:textColor="@drawable/tab_text_selector"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Eg xml file with Image as indicator

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_weight="1"
>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:src="@drawable/tab_indicator_world_selctor"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your answer only tackles the part of a customized indicator which is already implemented on my end. What I'm asking for is changing the color of the tabstrip. Besides I'm using a FragmentTabHost which is way different on my end compared to a TabHost.

Comment: the point of using custom indicator is that instead of using tabstrip you can include that into your xml layout and  remove it from tabwidget , FragmentTabHost and tabHost bothe take views in setIndicator method

Comment: I see, but I really wanted to stick on my codes for now and just to change the tabstip. Is there's no other way around to fix it?

Comment: You can try searching more but i didn't find one so i did it this way.

Comment: how to set your custom file as indicator?